# IMAP authenticate vs login

Tags: authentication, protocols, imap

IMAP servers may, according to [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#ref-TLS), supports these (and other) commands:

- `LOGIN`
- `AUTHENTICATE "PLAIN"`

## Questions

1. Is there a reason to use one above the other?
2. Is there a reason to support other `AUTHENTICATION` mechanisms when TLS is used?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You might be right, @jww. Originally I posted it here because I was "implementing" the RFC, and therefore programming. But to be fairly honest, I don't feel the urge to post it elsewhere, as it has already been answered successfully. Thanks for caring, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all servers support LOGIN, which is the basic baseline version to authenticate.

AUTHENTICATE is an extensible generic command, which could support any SASL* authentication mechanism, or custom methods.

I would use login where available because it's a simpler command (no base64 or continuation responses).

Reasons to use AUTHENTICATE: supporting SSO or OAUTH scenarios, which have different requirements then just a username or password.

For example, to integrate well with GMail, OAUTH2 is the preferred mechanism, which has a custom AUTHENTICATE method.

*SASL is the Simple Authentication and Security Layer, which is a metaprotocol for authentication, described currently in RFC 4422.

Comment: Let me answer that orthogonally: A few AUTHENTICATE methods, google's in particular, are designed such that an IMAP client can autologin without needing not store the user's password. That's a very lovely feature.